# Evaluating conditions like if 90 <= score <= 100

Tags: python

How does python evaluate a compound conditional statement like getting a grade based on a score? Specifically:

```
score = 95
if 90 <= score <= 100:
  grade = "A"
```

The above code seem to work correctly and grade will be "A", however I'm confused about how this happens. Coming from a C++ background I would not expect this code to be correct. In fact based on my C++ experience, I would expect the above code to be equivalent to this code:

```
score = 95
if (90 <= score) <= 100:
  grade = "A"
```

This code would evaluate (90 <= score) to be true, and then compare true to 100

However, python seems to evaluate the top code like this:

```
score = 95
if (90 <= score) and (score <= 100):
  grade = "A"
```

So I'm looking for the python documentation that explains how the compound conditional statement works so I can understand the first example I wrote in this thread.

Comment: `a <= c <= b` is equivalent to `a <=c and c <=b`, also it's a normal conditional statement written in a different way

Comment: Also look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: You expect if a <= c is false than c <= b condition are not evaluated? Or something similar about condition evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

That's just how the language is: comparisons can be chained.

Here's the doc about this topic: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

> (...) unlike C, expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Comment: I already found and added a dupe for it!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Well, it seems like the question was marked as a dupe a short moment after my answer was processed

Comment: aah okay, if you want, you can remove your answer

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you Devesh!